# Tabular measure groups and dimension processing

Tags: tabular

I have a Tabular cube and i built an SSIS flow for incremental measure group processing using XMLA script. The script states the MeasureGroupID to process.

I have a Fact_Volume table in my tabular model, and the Fact_Volume table contains different measures and attribute fields (used for slicing).

I don't understand if the processing of the measure group using XMLA script is enough for both measures and attributes in Fact_Volume or do i also have to process the Fact_Volume as a dimension in the SSIS Analysis Services Processing Task Editor component?

[Analysis Services Processing Task Editor]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using the SSIS Analysis Services Processing Task for processing Tabular models, as the notion of "dimension", "attributes", etc. does not really make sense.

Instead, use SSMS to generate a Process script for the objects you need to process incrementally (tables or partitions), and put the generated XMLA code into an Analysis Services Execute DDL task within your SSIS package.

When processing a table (or one or more partitions of a table), you generally do not need to do any processing of other objects, unless you have calculated columns in your model, that depend on the data in the table that was just processed. In that case, you should perform a Process Calculate on the entire model after the table has been processed.